# why this error "The method addFirst(int) is undefined for the type linklistJava(67108964)"

Tags: java, linked-list

package linkedlist;

public class linklist {
public static class Node
{
int data;
Node next;
public Node(int data)
{
this.data=data;
this.next=null;
}

```
    public static Node head;
    public static Node tail;

public void addFirst(int data){
        Node newNode =new Node(data);
        if(head==null){
            head=tail=newNode;
            return;
        }
        newNode.next=head;
        head=newNode;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   linklist ll =new linklist();
   ll.addFirst(1);
    
}
```

}

was expecting to add 1 into link list

Comment: the code you shared is incomplete, it would not compile. What is `linklist` class? There is no such thing in Java. Maybe you wanted to use `java.util.LinkedList`, that one also has a method `addFirst`

Answer (score 2):

I think your `.addFirst(int data)` method is not accesible because it doesn't belong to class `linklist`. It belongs to the inner class `Node`.